# Printing adding an extra plus sign before equal sign in python

Tags: python

So my code is this:

```
until = int(input("Until: "))
number = 1
result = 1
calculation = ""

while result < until:
    number += 1
    result = result + number
    calculation += f"{number} + "
    print(f"Calculated {calculation} = {result}")
```

And it prints:

```
Until: 10
Calculated 2 +  = 3
Calculated 2 + 3 +  = 6
Calculated 2 + 3 + 4 +  = 10
```

and I would like to get rid of the extra plus sign before the equal sign so this 4 +  = 10 would look like this 4 = 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use `slice strings`.
- I think the `number` and `result` begin with `0` would make more sense, otherwise you will get some weird expression like `2 = 3` or `2 + 3 = 6`.

#### code:

```
until = int(input("Until: "))
number = 0
result = 0
calculation = ""
while result < until:
    number += 1
    result = result + number
    calculation += f"{number} + "
    print(f"Calculated {calculation[:-3]} = {result}")
```

#### result:

```
Until: 10
Calculated 1 = 1
Calculated 1 + 2 = 3
Calculated 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
Calculated 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10

Until: 1
Calculated 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
until = int(input("Until: "))
number = 1
result = 1
calculation = ""

while result < until:
    number += 1
    result = result + number
    if calculation != "":
        calculation += " + "
    calculation += f"{number}"
    print(f"Calculated {calculation} = {result}")
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add plus sign after print function, like

```
until = int(input("Until: "))
number = 1
result = 1
calculation = ""

while result < until:
    number += 1
    result = result + number
    calculation += f"{number}"
    print(f"Calculated {calculation} = {result}")
    calculation += "+"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of adding the plus sign

```
until = int(input("Until: "))
number = 1
result = 1
calculation = ""

while result < until:
    number += 1
    result = result + number
    calculation += f"{number} "
    print(f"Calculated {calculation} = {result}")
    calculation += "+ "
```